# How to find cluster node ip address

Tags: kubernetes

Minikube has the specific node ip address (192.168.99.100) for single cluster, if I using kubeadm to create many nodes cluster, what should I do to find this ip address?

Answer (score 23):

This should be fairly straightforward: `kubectl get nodes -o wide`

Answer (score 7):

This command display the nodes name, private and public IP addresses.

```bash
kubectl get nodes -o wide | awk -v OFS='\t\t' '{print $1, $6, $7}'
```

Comment: Is the kubectl print column even in fixed order?

Answer (score 4):

generally, there is no such thing as a single IP of a kubernetes cluster. Minikube has it, because it's a special 1 node case. Most production clusters will be one way or another operating with many network-internal, cluster-internal and external IP addresses. For example each node is usually deployed on a separate (virtual) machine that has it's own IP address, either external or network-internal (like 10.x.y.z or 192.168.x.y) depending on your network setup. Moreover, many kubernetes objects, like pods or services have their IPs also (cluster-internal or external).
Now the question is what do you need the IP for:

- if you are looking for the address of your kubernetes API endpoint server (the endpoint to which `kubectl` talks) then in case of clusters created manually with `kubeadm`, this will be the IP of the master node that you created with `kubeadm init` command (assuming single master case). See [this official doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/create-cluster-kubeadm/#considerations-about-apiserver-advertise-address-and-controlplaneendpoint) for details. To talk to your cluster using `kubectl` you will need some authorization data except its IP: see subsequent sections of the mentioned document how to obtain it.
- if you are looking for the IP of a `LoadBalancer` type service, then it will be reported among lots of other stuff in the output of `kubectl get service name-of-your-service -o yaml` or `kubectl describe service name-of-your-service`. Note however that clusters created with `kubeadm` don't provide external load-balancers on their own (that's why they are called external) and if you intend to setup a fully functional production cluster manually, you will need to use something like [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/) in addition.
- if you are looking for IPs of `NodePort` type services then these will be all the IPs of worker node (virtual) machines that you assimilated into you cluster by running `kubeadm join` command on them. if you don't remember them then you can use `kubectl get nodes -o wide` as suggested in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59999460/1220560).

Comment: How should I find the ip address for ingress to expose service to the internet?

Comment: @ccd it depends how you deploy ingress-controller: see [my answer to your other question here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60015214/1220560)

Answer (score 2):

To get informations about `Kubernetes objects` you should use `kubectl get <resource>` or `kubectl describe <resource>`.

In [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#get)

> Display one or many resources
>
> Prints a table of the most important information about the specified resources. You can filter the list using a label selector and the --selector flag. If the desired resource type is namespaced you will only see results in your current namespace unless you pass --all-namespaces.

If you will check manual for `kubectl get` you will get information about `-o` flag.

> -o, --output='': Output format. One of:
>   json|yaml|wide|name|custom-columns=...|custom-columns-file=...|go-template=...|go-template-file=...|jsonpath=...|jsonpath-file=...
>   See custom columns [http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl-overview/#custom-columns], golang template
>   [http://golang.org/pkg/text/template/#pkg-overview] and jsonpath template
>   [http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath].

Thats mean you can get output in `YAMLs` or `JSON` format. Detailed information can be found in [this doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#output-options).

As @Bernard Halas mentioned, you can just use `kubectl get nodes -o wide`.

Another option is use `describe` with `grep`. `-A` will print number lines of trailing context. Its helpful if you need to get list about information per node.

```
$ kubectl describe node | grep Addresses: -A 4
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.164.0.63
  ExternalIP:   35.204.67.223
  InternalDNS:  gke-test-default-pool-d11b1330-g44z.c.composite-rune-239911.internal
  Hostname:     gke-test-default-pool-d11b1330-g44z.c.composite-rune-239911.internal
--
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.164.0.61
  ExternalIP:   35.204.63.113
  InternalDNS:  gke-test-default-pool-d11b1330-gtpj.c.composite-rune-239911.internal
  Hostname:     gke-test-default-pool-d11b1330-gtpj.c.composite-rune-239911.internal
--
Addresses:
  InternalIP:   10.164.0.62
  ExternalIP:   35.204.202.107
  InternalDNS:  gke-test-default-pool-d11b1330-r4dw.c.composite-rune-239911.internal
  Hostname:     gke-test-default-pool-d11b1330-r4dw.c.composite-rune-239911.internal
```

You can also use `YAML` or `JSON` format. Output will be similar to previous one.

```
$ kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep addresses: -A 8
    addresses:
    - address: 10.164.0.63
      type: InternalIP
    - address: 35.204.67.223
      type: ExternalIP
    - address: gke-test-default-pool-d11b1330-g44z.c.composite-rune-239911.internal
      type: InternalDNS
    - address: gke-test-default-pool-d11b1330-g44z.c.composite-rune-239911.internal
      type: Hostname
...
```

In addition if you will need some specific output (only information you need and ar not print as default) you can use [custom columns](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/overview/#custom-columns). It's based on `YAML` format.

```
$ kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=Name:.metadata.name,NS:.metadata.namespace,HostIP:.status.hostIP,PodIP:status.podIP,REQ_CPU:.spec.containers[].resources.requests.cpu
Name                          NS        HostIP        PodIP       REQ_CPU
httpd-5d8cbbcd67-gtzcx        default   10.164.0.63   10.32.2.7   100m
nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-54dds        default   10.164.0.62   10.32.1.5   100m
nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-54ggt        default   10.164.0.62   10.32.1.3   100m
nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-bz86v        default   10.164.0.62   10.32.1.4   100m
nginx-7cdbd8cdc9-zcvrf        default   10.164.0.62   10.32.1.2   100m
nginx-test-59df8dcb7f-hlrcr   default   10.164.0.63   10.32.2.4   100m
```

Comment: The final command `kubectl get pods -o custom-columns=...` allowed me to get Node IPs even though our company's AKS cluster blocks the `kubectl get nodes -o...` query.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a command that should show the internal IP addresses of each node in the cluser:

```
ubuntu@astrocyte:~$ kubectl get nodes -o yaml | grep -- "- address:"
    - address: 192.168.1.6
    - address: astrocyte
    - address: 192.168.1.20
    - address: axon2.local
    - address: 192.168.1.7
    - address: axon3.local
```

It also shows hostnames, if you have them configured

Answer (score 0):

Simplest ways is

```
kubectl get nodes -o wide
```