# Ingress without ip address

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I create a ingress to expose my internal service.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: app-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
        - path: /app
          backend:
            serviceName: my-app
            servicePort: 80
```

But when I try to get this ingress, it show it has not ip address.

```
NAME          HOSTS                ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
app-ingress   example.com                    80      10h
```

The service show under below.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-app
spec:
  selector:
    app: my-app
  ports:
  - name: my-app
    nodePort: 32000
    port: 3000
    targetPort: 3000
  type: NodePort
```

Answer (score 2):

Note: I'm guessing because of the [other question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59999345/1220560) that you are trying to create an ingress on a manually created cluster with `kubeadm`.

As described in [the docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#prerequisites), in order for ingress to work, you need to install [ingress controller](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress-controllers/) first. An ingress object itself is merely a configuration slice for the installed ingress controller.

[Nginx based controller](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/) is one of the most popular choice. Similarly to services, in order to get a single failover-enabled VIP for your ingress, you need to use [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/). Otherwise you can deploy ingress-nginx over a node port: see details [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/baremetal/)

Finally, `servicePort` in your ingress object should be 3000, same as `port` of your service.

Comment: But I only open the 80 port, how should I set 3000 refer to it?

Comment: read again: `servicePort` in your ingress object should be the `port` of your service, so that the ingress controller knows how to reach your service. it has nothing to do with the fact on which port the ingress controller is exposed.