# How to config loadBalancer service to reach to internet

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service object of type `LoadBalancer`:

```
NAMESPACE       NAME            TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                                                                      AGE
default         user-api        LoadBalancer   10.106.120.69    <pending>     9411:31622/TCP,3000:31878/TCP,4000:30202/TCP,3001:31656/TCP,4001:31455/TCP   96m
```

I can reach to the service internally with 3000 port via `internal_ip:31878`.

Supposing I have a public_ip and ingress, how should I correctly configure it to let the internal service to reach to the internet?

```
NAME          HOSTS                ADDRESS   PORTS   AGE
app-ingress   user-api.my-domain.com         80      95m
```

Answer (score 2):

again, I'm guessing that this was a cluster setup by `kubeadm` because of your [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59999345/1220560) and again the solution is to install an external load-balancer plugin such as [metalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf/). After that your loadbalancers will get IPs assigned automatically and all ports of your services/ingress will be open on this IP and will lead to your pods.

Installing metalLB is very easy:

1. `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/google/metallb/v0.8.3/manifests/metallb.yaml`
2. create and apply config of IP pools to be used for your load-balancers similarly to [this one](https://metallb.universe.tf/configuration/#layer-2-configuration):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  namespace: metallb-system
  name: config
data:
  config: |
    address-pools:
    - name: default
      protocol: layer2
      addresses:
      - 92.18.1.200-92.18.1.250
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a service object of type `LoadBalancer`, you should already be able to reach to the service from the Internet. If you have a Load Balancer that is attached to an Ingress Controller, you should change the type of your service object (to something like `ClusterIP`) and register the service in the Ingress Controller manifest. Example is:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: test-ingress
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /<context-path>
        backend:
          serviceName: <service-name>
          servicePort: <service-port>
```

Comment: I tried this, but also cannot access the service through `user-api.my-domain.com/context-path/my-service`.